# When do German Ashkenazim make havdalah?

Tags: minhag, zemanim, ashkenazi, havdalah, yekke

I know that there are several opinions regarding the calculation​ of the time of motsei Shabbas. What method of calculating the time for Havdalah is used in German Ashkenaz minhag?

Comment: Havdala can be made at Plag HaMincha (10.75 hours into the day) according to all opinions, including German ones. Are you asking how to divide the day into 12 hours (dawn-dusk or sunrise-sunset)?

Comment: I think I remember that the [GGBH community in London](http://ggbh.info/) once had a different time for motzoei shabbos than that of the rest of the community. Maybe the OP is referring to this.

Comment: Yes. I meant which of the different opinions was followed by German Jews.

Comment: Historically, we've followed the Rishonim. However, we generally hold like the Gr"A for zemanim now, as may be understood by the fact that our סזק"ש follows his shitta (Wiesenthal, תפלה שפת ישראל)

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I think that the Vilna Gaon's timing is used because its the opinion of the Terumas HaDeshen.

Comment: German Jews in Germany, like all Jews everywhere before quite recently, used the method of "Go outside and look up at the sky and wait till you see three stars". How modern urbanites approximate that practice with math is not really based in their ancestor's minhag.